# How do you calculate ND filter value of gray sunglasses and the colored sunglasses?

Tags: f-stop, highlights, nd-filter

I had the idea of using my sunglasses as ND filter when F/16 didn't help in a beach scene with my MC 2500 but then realized something weird. My green Ray Ban cockpit sunglasses claim to block 85% of the visible light but the scenery was not quite dark as I expected it to be.

So. If the claimed number of eighty five percent is true. What is the ND number and F stop reduction of an Ray Ban Cockpit sunglasses with G(reen) 15 lens along with its polarizer variant? What makes it quite complex is how it claims to eliminate all the blue light and it gets even more jarring when I think about brown lenses of my O Marines that eliminate green color which has two times the sensitivity in cameras with Bayer pattern.

So basically. How do you calculate ND values of colored and not colored lenses?

Comment: How much did it block, and what were you expecting?  (Before and after exposure settings would be nice.)

Comment: @xiota sadly. Its been months since I did the shoot and I dont have access to the camcorder anymore along with the fact that I have memory issues.

Comment: Assuming the manufacturer claim is accurate *and* applicable to photography, you could use logs to figure out the number of stops.    But it might still not work because of light leaks or other issues.  You could just measure the effect of your sunglasses and write them down on a tag.

Comment: @xiota thanks for the idea. I realized I have access to my Nikon D80. I should try it by cropping the area. I will have to wait for tomorrow though.

Comment: Alternatively, just set your camera for Aperture Priority and select some f/stop. See what the camera says is proper exposure. Now place the glasses over the lens...what is the camera now showing as proper exposure? I think the problem you are going to run into is that ND filters attempt to cut light evenly across the spectrum, where your glasses do not. Depending on the scene, you may blow a channel while underexposing the others, comparatively speaking.

Comment: Ignoring spectral color variations: A 1-stop filter is 1/2 the light, a 2-stop filter is 1/4 the light, and a 3-stop filter is 1/8 the light or 12.5% which means 87.5% of the light is blocked. So your sunglasses would be just shy of a 3-stop filter or ND8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters subtract some of the light that ordinarily would traverse the lens. This action reduces the available exposing energy. An under-exposure will result unless compensation is applied.

Fortunately most modern cameras measure exposure light energy using a thru-the-lens system. This system will detect light loss due to the mounted filter and apply necessary compensations.

Filter compensation, in the jargon of the photographer is called “filter factor”. If your camera sports through-the-lens metering, knowing the filter factor had how to apply might be moot. On the other hand, there is good reason to know the filter factor.

The filter factor can be applied by multiplication as an aid to compensation by means of shutter speed. As an example, suppose the filter factor is known to be 4. Say the shutter speed is 1/400 of a second without filter. We mount a filter with a factor of 4 and multiply 1/400 X 4. This math is 1/400 X 4/1 = 4/400 = 1/100 (fraction manipulation is not the easiest). In this case, the revised shutter speed is 1/100 of a second.

Another way to apply a filter factor is to alter the aperture to compensate. This translates to opening the aperture. We need to know how many f-stops the filter factor signifies.  To accomplish, count on your fingers by twos i.e. 2 – 4 – 8 – 16 in other words a filter factor of 2 is one finger or 1 f-stop. A filter factor of 4 is two fingers or 2-f-stops. A filter factor of 8 is 3 fingers or 3 f-stops etc.

Knowing all this, point the camera at a mundane expanse like blue sky or a white wall and allow the camera to meter this vista. The camera will display an exposure via shutter and aperture combination.

Now mount the sunglass (filter). The exposure will alter and the camera will display revised data. Note the difference and using the math explained above; compute the filter factor you observed.

Comment: Thank you. From 1/800 to the 1/100 which means three exposure stop  difference.

Comment: @ Delta Oscar Uniform -- 1/800 to 1/400 to 1/200 to 1/100 of a second = 3 f-stop = filter factor 8. In the jargon of photo density, 1 f-stop = 0.3 density units -- 2 f-stops = 0.6 density  -- 3 f-stop = 0.90 density -- 4 f-stops = 1.20 density -- 5 f-stops = 1.5 density. Density is log notation like magnitude or Richter Scale or dB Scale for sound.